# How to fix a 'list index out of range' error?

Tags: python

This code gives me an 'index out of range' error once 'higher' is entered for the second time. HELP?!

```
import random
print("Think of a number from 1 to 100")
nums = list(range(0, 101))
correct = 0
counter = 0
while correct == 0:
    counter += 1
    guess = nums[int(len(nums) / 2)]
    higher_lower = input("Is this your number: " + str(guess) + "? If not, 
    is your number higher or lower or than " + str(guess) + "?: ")
    if higher_lower == "higher":
        nums = nums[guess:]
        print(nums)
    elif higher_lower == "lower":
        nums = nums[:guess]
        print(nums)
    elif higher_lower == "yes":
        correct = 1
print("I have guessed your number " + str(guess) + " in " + str(counter) + 
" guesses")
```

It is supposed to guess the user's number by asking the user if it is higher or lower than it's current guess.

Comment: `nums = nums[guess:]` shortens your list... If the real number was 70 and I guessed 65; neither index would be valid after the first round.

Comment: I suggest you rethink your solution. Rather than keeping a list of all possible guesses, you can store three numbers: current guess, highest guess so far, and lowest guess so far. Also, read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for tips on debugging your code.

Answer (score 0):

### What do you want guess to be?

In your code, `guess` is obviously the number currently being guessed, but in `nums=nums[:guess]`, you also use it as an index. This is fine as long as only values from the end are removed, but, as soon as you remove stuff from the beginning, everything will shift backwards, possibly(?) out of range.

#### How do you fix this

1. Use `.index()` to get the index
2. Use `guess` as index, this means setting it to `len(nums)//2` and using `nums[guess]` in the text
3. Use a different, (more) memory-efficient: store the highest value the secret number is lower than, the lowest value it is higher than and then guess `(lower_than - higher_than) // 2`.